# How can I import TemplateDoesNotExist in app engine (python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I can't believe I'm not able to find this, but this is quite simple:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

try :
  content = template.render(...)
except TemplateDoesNotExist:
  content = ...
```

Then I don't know how to import TemplateDoesNotExist! Can anyone tell me its module path? Thanks!

Comment: Use the source! *jedi hand wave*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TemplateDoesNotExist` is defined in django.template   However from what you are doing it appears your going down a deprecated path under Python 2.7 .  If you have a look at the template.py you just imported `from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template` you will see the following deprecation warning.

```
_PYTHON27_DEPRECATION = (
'google.appengine.ext.webapp.template is deprecated. Please use another '
'templating system such as django.template or jinja2.')
```

You haven't said if your using python 2.5 or python 2.7 .  If your starting a new project the recommendation from google is to use 2.7.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7, but it seems I need to find another document? Those on App Engine's site don't describe how to use django framework.

Comment: To be honest, if you don't actually need django I would just use webapp2 and jinja2 (for templating).  Much simpler.

Comment: OK, I think I'll instead use open and IOError to detect if the template file exists. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using python 2.7 and importing template as

`from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template`

Then you can import the exception as

`from google.appengine._internal.django.template import TemplateDoesNotExist`

and then

`try:
  template.render(...)
except TemplateDoesNotExist:
  # do something useful`